# Whats the on heap memory footprint of a DirectByteBuffer in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

The vast majority of a DirectByteBuffer - if large enough - is allocated off the Java Heap. But a portion of it will still be on the heap, even if its very small.

How many bytes does a DirectByteBuffer of any size take up on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously implementation defined, as the Java spec doesn't make any guarantees about this stuff. For a modern hotspot VM: 2 words overhead per object (and to be exact at least 1 word for variables even if the object doesn't have any). Now you basically have to count. Every object has to be 8byte aligned.

As an example lets look at DirectByteBuffer: We see that it stores one object (1 word). Now if it shares this object with something else you may or may not want to count it. If you count it you'll have to find out what object is stored and compute its size as well (therefore depends on your exact codepath). Since DirectByteBuffer extends a class you'll have to add that size as well to it.

Yep that's quite some work and I sure as hell won't do it for you ;) But it's quite simple. I count at least 3 references and 29byte primitives..

Answer (score 0):

A very small number. Enough for its monitor, its class reference, its mark, position, limit, and capacity, and a reference to the direct data array.

If the data array is small enough that you have to worry about the overheads maybe you shouldn't be using one at all.

Comment: I'm using a ton of them. Thus the question. My assumption is 64 bit reference to the direct data array, 64 bits again for the class reference, and 32 * 4 bits for the mark, position, limit, and capacity. I'm assuming a 64bit jvm.